# Search file content with regex in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to search for a string that looks like this: "tt1234567" in all files with a specific file extension in a specific folder

This works on Linux:

```
find /media/ -name "*.txt" -exec grep -oa "tt[0-9]\{7\}" {} \;
```

How can I rewrite that to batch?
Maybe something like this?

```
cd C:\media\
dir /S /B *.txt >> [A little code that matches (tt[0-9]{7})] >> c:\blabla.txt
```

Comment: what kind of output are you looking for? An explorer window with a "search"? or... ?

Comment: @BenStrombeck I just want a the result printed in a text file. One matched string per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Removed possibly problematic quotes.
**EDIT:** Fixed Code.

`FINDSTR.EXE` does not correctly implement the REGEX standard, so matching [0-9] 0 through a specified amount of times will not work AFAIK.

```
cd C:\media\
for /f %%x in ('dir /S /B *.txt') do (
  echo %%x| findstr /r "^tt[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[tT][xX][tT]$" >> c:\blabla.txt
)
```

Do not put a space between `%%x` and `|`, or it will fail to match.

It is not necessary to split the `FOR` command into three lines, I did so just for readability.
You can remove `(` and `)` and put it all on one line.

---

Alternatively you can download and use `SED`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm I get these errors: FINDSTR: Cannot open {}
FINDSTR: Cannot open \; >> c:\blabla.txt

Comment: The input is just a lot of text files with these ids in them. The output should just be a text file with the ids separated by something like a linebreak (doesn't matter what. can also be a space).

Comment: @Patrik - I'm not good with regex expressions, please give me an example filename that should pass the test.

Comment: The ids looks like this: tt1234567. The filenames can be anything. The file ending is however the same.

Comment: Just manage to fix it by my self: `cd C:\media\
for /f %%x in ('dir /S /B *.txt') do (
 findstr /r tt[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %%x >> c:\blabla.txt
)`

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` has the pipe operator, so you can use

```
dir /S /B *.txt | findstr "tt[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0.9][0-9][0-9]\.txt$" >> c:\blabla.txt
```

- `findstr` has regex and case-insensitive options turned on by default.
- The (very limited) regex syntax supported by `findstr` is documented in the [TechNet Library](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).